# Generating thumbnails vs Styling images

Tags: php, html, css, image

I have an ecommerce site in which i have to display some products i.e 40-50 products per page.Every product has an image which displays the image of the product.

The main thing is that in the database i have a meduim/high quality image of the product whose dimensions would be around 720px-1024 px , these can vary and every image has dimensions in between these two.

Now, i have two different ways of displaying these images for product, i could use a php script to generate thumbnails from these pics whose dimensions would be 290X290 or i could use the style tag and set the width and height as 290X290 and source as the real image.

Let me explain this by an example.

Original Image

[image]

I could do this to display the image

- `<img src="/imagethumbnail.php?product_id=34"/>`
- `<img style="height:290px;width:290px" src="productimg.png"/>`

finall image

[image]

one calls a php script and generate a thumbnail image of size 290X290 while the other one simply uses the style tag.

Both of them are working fine but i think when i use the style tags i see a trade off in image quality.While when i use the script to generate the image i see a trade off in image generation like they take sometime to show up on the page.

What would be the better method to do this and what would be the perfect solution towards it?

Comment: This will increase page size and loading time <img style="height:290px;width:290px" src="productimg.png"/>

Comment: when uploading a new image. try creating a different size for their different uses, just like for thumbnail or big preview. that way, you wouldn't be repeating the same thing forever.

Comment: @MdHasiburRahaman okaay , noted down.

Comment: @Semi-Friends i was thinking about the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the standard method is to generate the thumbnails in advance. And you should probably set the width and height in the markup as attributes on the img element, rather than under the style attribute.